# Convert html tags to php array

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I have a system status page from a partner that I am trying to convert so that I can automate its input into my own service page. The status of the service is provided by a `<span>` class. I know this is far from ideal but this is the only way that they provide updates.

Below is a copy of the HTML:

```
<ul class="item-3">
    <li class="status service1">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 1
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="status service2">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 2
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="status service3">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h6>
        SERVICE 3
        </h6>
        <p>
        Updated:
        9:52 AM CST Apr, 24
        </p>
        <span class="arrow up"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to grab the `<span class="arrow up">` values as this is the service status, and the `<li class="status service3">` as this tells me what service it is.

Since my status page API uses IDs and not "up/down" etc I will need the statuses and services to be in arrays so I can convert them into my formats.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592438/create-array-from-the-contents-of-div-tags-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);

$result = $xml->xpath('//ul/li');
$up = array(); //array of servises that is 'up'
$down = array(); //array of servises that is 'down'
foreach ($result as $item)
{
    if (strpos($item->span[1]->attributes()->class, 'up') !== false)
    {
        $up[] = str_replace("status ", "", $item->attributes()->class);
    }

    if (strpos($item->span[1]->attributes()->class, 'down') !== false)
    {
        $down[] = str_replace("status ", "", $item->attributes()->class);
    }
}

var_dump($up);
var_dump($down);
```

Will output for "Up" system status

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "service1"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "service2"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "service3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dumkaaa but how do i tell this to load the html from the file?

Comment: @red-spider simple use file_get_contents lo load from other website:
`$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com');`
or from your site include_path
`// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);`

Comment: thanks @Dumkaaa , that seem to load it in, however i still seem to have an issue getting this to work right. I can output the entire SimpleXMLElement but not the array example you showed above.

Comment: @red-spider `var_dump($up)` shows the array of services with "up" statuses

Comment: That outputs `NULL` and `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: up`

Comment: perfect, that works, thanks! :) now begins the fun part for me to get the data into my system :D @Dumkaaa